# How to count specific value occurancies for x amount of rows in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count

I have Pandas DataFrame:

```
df  = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
```

I need to count not all occurancies of columnn `'gender'`, but for the first 5 entries (would love to see code for any interval of rows, let's say from 10th to the 20th etc.)

Currently I am familliar only with this:

```
df[df['gender'] == 1].shape[0]
```

and more complicated with lambda:

```
A2_object = df.apply(lambda x: True if x['gender'] == 1 else False, axis=1)
A2 = len(A2_object[A2_object == True].index)
```

I am learning, and I see that loops don't work in dataframe the same way as in the lists or dictionaries.

I am trying something like that:

```
df[df['gender'] == 1 and df.index < 5].shape[0]
```

I love this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values), but can't get my head around the examples.

Comment: `df.iloc[start:end]['gender'].eq(1).sum()`

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. @Quang-Hoang posted, I needed to use slicing for indecies and in dataframe format indecies are .iloc (.loc?). Thank you, Sir.

Answer: `df.iloc[start:end]['gender'].eq(1).sum()`